PostgreSQL Recursive Delete with Foreign Key Constraint
In my PostgreSQL table, when I try to delete a record, I encounter the following error:
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: update or delete on table "parent_table" violates foreign key constraint "parent_table_header_ref_id_id_4fd15d08_fk" on table "child_table"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "child_table".

This happens even with ON DELETE RESTRICT enabled. Is there any script or a PostgreSQL function/loop that can be used to recursively delete data, ensuring that all related records across multiple levels are deleted safely when foreign key constraints are in place?
Python Pseudo code:
def delete_record(query):
    while True:
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
            break
        except Exception as exception:
            # exception = 'SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: update or delete on table "parent_table" violates foreign key constraint "parent_table_header_ref_id_id_4fd15d08_fk" on table "child_table"'
            child_table_delete_query = get_delete_query(exception)
            # child_table_delete_query = 'delete from child_table where header_ref_id_id = 1'
            delete_record(child_table_delete_query)

delete_record('delete from parent_table where id = 1')


It happens because you have ON DELETE RESTRICT. If you want the delete of the parent to also delete the child, you need to define it as ON DELETE CASCADE.

@Mark: Consider creating an answer to settle this.

If you have new question, ask a new question; please don't edit new questions into existing questions.

I found a solution to recursively delete PostgreSQL table data with a WHERE condition. While TRUNCATE TABLE <table_name> CASCADE; works, it's very risky as it lacks the functionality to specify a WHERE condition.
To address this, I wrote a Python script that recursively deletes table data with a WHERE condition and includes a feature to ask for confirmation before deleting the data.
Here's an example of how to use the script:
Please Type Delete Query: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 13;

You can access the script here: recursive_delete.py
Feel free to contribute if you'd like to convert this into a PL/PGSQL script.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.

It happens because you have ON DELETE RESTRICT. If you want the delete of the parent to also delete the child, you need to define it as ON DELETE CASCADE.
